# Word for a frequent behaviour?

Tags: nouns

Don't know whether it's an English literature question or a psychology one but one may have witnessed a very frequent behavior associated with bosses or maybe teachers where they start asking you questions (assuming you are brilliant enough), you start answering them but they don't stop until they have got a question you can't answer...then ridicule you for not answering that last question forgetting the former ones..

Is there a word for the boss's or teacher's behaviour? Is there some named disease for it?

Comment: _Often_ only modifies verb phrases; you mean a _frequent_ behavior. As for the name, this is referred to in the USA as "assholistic behavior", and persons who display it are often referred to as "assholes". This is not a polite term; however, it's not polite behavior.

Comment: I believe the word you seek is humiliation or more broadly, initiation. The military call it hazing.

Comment: The problem w/ your question is that there are two different concepts here: ramping up the difficulty of the questions (testing to failure? training? drawing out the student?) and then the ridicule (shaming, peer pressure, insecurity, or plain jerkdom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bullying - abuse of authority that simply does not merit a decent descriptive term.

But it should come under ***rankism*** defined as abusive, discriminatory, or exploitative behavior towards people because of their rank in a particular hierarchy.

see [***rankism***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankism).

Comment: Thnx its quiet close however it seems there isn't yet any particular word for it...

Answer (score 1):

The [Socratic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_seminars) is a form of teaching where the teacher asks questions meant to make the student think, and then gain understanding into the subject matter at hand.

Comment: True. But if the student's only response is "What a jerk!", little learning has been accomplished. Putting people down is not a way of teaching, but a way of dominating and punishing.

Comment: "testing to failure" is another concept that doesn't include the ridicule component

Answer (score 1):

It is a bossy, domineering, overbearing, high-handed behaviour. (behavior in US-English)

Yes, there is a name for it : "hidden inferiority complex". They try to crush the "inferiors", because they are not too sure about themselves.

See the life of a famous and infamous dictator : he missed everything in his life, until, unfortunately, the circumstances gave him the opportunity to be almighty, and take revenge of his failures.